# Blender says I have Maya and 3Dsmax?

Tags: interface

I was working in blender playing with nodes when the program crashed. I opened it and immediately noticed a dropdown box near Blender, which I have never seen before as well as the Hash number there.

[image: Weird message]

I clicked on the dropdown menu and it says that I have 3Dsmax and Maya, both of which I have never used in my entire life. I looked up the hash number to see if that was an error of some sort but had no luck finding any related info. Does anyone know what this is and why it has 2017 as the date?

I genuinely have no idea what tags to give this and I didn't want to put this in the wrong section, so if anyone knows what the right tag for this is, please let me know and I'll update it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not to indicate that you have 3DSmax or Maya, but to allow you to change the way you interact with Blender to be more similar to the way you would interact with those applications.

Comment: Thank you for that, also would you happen to know anything about the hash number or why the date on the program is showing 2017 instead of 2018 like it usually does?

Comment: The date refers to when that build of Blender was compiled by the developers. I'm not sure what the hash number is for, I believe it relates to development.

Comment: All those data including Interaction dropdown, Date and Hash were present on the Blender's splashscreen for many years already

Comment: The hash number is the commit hash, which identifies  what revision of the code this build of Blender was made from. You can look these up in the changelog if you're curious: https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/